# Orchard 1.8 – Media Library items sync with physical folders

Tags: orchardcms, media

I have a new install of Orchard 1.8 and need to sync all images in the /media/default/ directory to the Media Library catalog of items (‘Media’ link in Dashboard). Currently the Media Library lists only the FOLDERS but not the items (images, docs, etc.) within them – only when the import is done online does it include the image and offer a preview.

I saw a [similar post being asked for version 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784161/orchard-1-7-contents-of-media-folders-not-listed-in-media-library) and Bertrand’s answer was ‘Enable the Update feature and migrate your media to the media library from there’ – yet I have no clue on how to accomplish this.

Can anyone list the steps needed to do a one-time sync of all items into the Media Library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the admin menu click Modules, then find the "Upgrade" feature and click enable. This adds a new menu item called "Upgrade to 1.8", select this and then select the Media tab. Then click Migrate under Migrating Media Files.

Basically exactly as Bertrand said ;) He also has a blog post with more details:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/dude-where-are-my-images

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had mind-block with the upgrade feature since I thought it must be for upgrading from previous versions and never got to try the steps mentioned. It works fine.